# How to read custom variables from Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm making an extension for chrome to visualize the js structure but for some reason I am not able to access custom js variables from the extension. How could I read these vars/properties? like knowing if jQuery exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content scripts run in [*isolated world*](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#execution-environment):

> They **cannot**:
>
> - Use variables or functions defined by web pages or by other content scripts

You should try injecting a `<script src='injected.js'><script>` (this script should be able to 'see' the web page defined variables and functions) to page header from content script and then establishing a communication between these two. Content script and injected script can talk simply over DOM (by ie. posting messages in a hidden div) or, better, using [postMessage/addEventListener](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#host-page-communication).